# Correct order of functions

Tags: javascript

Which order should these be in?

https://jsfiddle.net/v8uoy1xw/2/

function upTo

function show(el)

function hide(el)

**or this?**

function show(el)

function hide(el)

function upTo

```
   function upTo(el, selector) {
     while (el.matches(selector) === false) {
       el = el.parentNode;
     }
     return el;
   }

   function show(el) {
     el.classList.remove("hide");
   }

   function hide(el) {
     el.classList.add("hide");
   }
```

Comment: Since they are not called in the script you show, there is no need for a specific order. Please use `<>` to create a [mcve] and explain expected and actual output if you want more help

Comment: Here: https://jsfiddle.net/v8uoy1xw/2/

Comment: The order in which they are declared in doesn't matter.

Comment: Also, your fiddle doesn't have any HTML to it. Can you create a working fiddle and explain the problem you are having?

Comment: I just wanted to know if 1 was supposed to be at the top, that's all. https://jsfiddle.net/aebwrk6p/60/

Comment: Are you asking for some coding guidelines preferences? If yes - such questions are off-topic on SO as opinion based... Otherwise please [edit] post to clarify why you believe moving one particular function to the top would make any difference.

Comment: Maybe someone can answer this for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47486641/of-these-conditional-matches-which-do-you-like-the-best-and-least

Comment: @mplungjan  What about toggle?

Comment: Can you show me what you mean on jsfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/aebwrk6p/63/ And I'll take a look at it so I can see what you mean.

Comment: @mplungjan How do I implement that in the code, I tried but it's not working.

Comment: I see your code is not very optimised anyway so never mind

Comment: What do you mean by not very optimized?

Comment: DRY: Don’t Repeat Yourself. Any way. If your code works then you do not need to be concerned with the order of function declaration. If you are very concerned about how your code looks, then study and try to simplify the code you have.